# Index usage for database server

Tags: mysql, linux

How can i fix the Index usage on one of our database server?

It says from our Nagios control panel that:

```
Service: DB Index Usage
Host: MySQL Cluster 
Address: ( our IP )
State: CRITICAL

Additional Info:

CRITICAL - index usage  90.01%
```

Comment: Are you having performance problems, or are you just concerned about an arbitrary ratio set by the person who wrote a nagios check?

Comment: Yes i am just concerned about this alert! And this is the first time i encounter this.

Comment: Are you experiencing performance problems?  Are there new queries in the slow log?

Comment: yes there is a lot of slow queries that need to optimize now..

Comment: Then optimize the queries. This is a useless alert.